# Making processes wait until resource is loaded into shared memory using Boost.Interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, process, multiprocessing, boost-interprocess

Suppose I have `n` processes with IDs `1` to `n`. I have a file with lots of data, where each process will only store a disjoint subset of the data. I would like to load and process the file using exactly one process, store the resulting data in a data structure allocated via Boost.Interprocess in shared memory, and then allow any (including the one who loaded the file) process to read from the data.

For this to work, I need to make use of some of the Boost.Interprocess synchronization constructs located [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.conditions) to ensure processes do not try to read the data before it has been loaded. However, I am struggling with this part and it is likely due to my lack of experience in this area. At the moment, I have `process(1)` loading the file into shared memory and I need a way to ensure any given process cannot read the file contents until the load is complete, even if the read might happen arbitrarily long after the loading occurs.

I wanted to try and use a combination of a mutex and condition variable using the `notify_all` call so that `process(1)` can signal to the other processes it is okay to read from the shared memory data, but this seems to have an issue in that `process(1)` might send a `notify_all` call before some `process(i)` has even tried to `wait` for the condition variable to signal it is okay to read the data.

Any ideas for how to approach this in a reliable manner?

**Edit 1**

Here is my attempt to clarify my dilemma and express more clearly what I have tried. I have some class that I allocate into a shared memory space using Boost.Interprocess that has a form similar to the below:

```
namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

class cache {
public:
   
   cache() = default;
   ~cache() = default;

   void set_process_id(std::size_t ID) { id = ID; }

   void load_file(const std::string& filename) {
      
      // designated process to load
      // file has ID equal to 0
      if( id == 0 ){
          
         // lock using the mutex
         bi::scoped_lock<bi::interprocess_mutex> lock(m);
         
         // do work to process the file and
         // place result in the data variable

         // after processing file, notify all other
         // processes that they can access the data
         load_cond.notify_all();

      }


   }
   void read_into(std::array<double, 100>& data_out) {
       { // wait to read data until load is complete
          // lock using the mutex
          bi::scoped_lock<bi::interprocess_mutex> lock(m);
          load_cond.wait(lock);
       }

       data_out = data;
   }

private:
   
   size_t id;
   std::array<double, 100> data;
   bi::interprocess_mutex m;
   bi::interprocess_condition load_cond;

};
```

The above is roughly what I had when I asked the question but did not sit well with me because if the `read_into` method was called after the designated process executes the `notify_all` call, then the `read_into` would be stuck. What I just did this morning that seems to fix this dilemma is change this class to the following:

```
namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

class cache {
public:
   
   cache():load_is_complete(false){}
   ~cache() = default;

   void set_process_id(std::size_t ID) { id = ID; }

   void load_file(const std::string& filename) {
      
      // designated process to load
      // file has ID equal to 0
      if( id == 0 ){
          
         // lock using the mutex
         bi::scoped_lock<bi::interprocess_mutex> lock(m);
         
         // do work to process the file and
         // place result in the data variable

         // after processing file, notify all other
         // processes that they can access the data
         load_is_complete = true;
         load_cond.notify_all();

      }


   }
   void read_into(std::array<double, 100>& data_out) {
       { // wait to read data until load is complete
          // lock using the mutex
          bi::scoped_lock<bi::interprocess_mutex> lock(m);
          if( not load_is_complete ){
             load_cond.wait(lock);
          }
       }

       data_out = data;
   }

private:
   
   size_t id;
   std::array<double, 100> data;
   bool load_is_complete;
   bi::interprocess_mutex m;
   bi::interprocess_condition load_cond;

};
```

Not sure if the above is the most elegant, but I believe it should ensure processes cannot access the data being stored in shared memory until it has completed loading, whether they get to the mutex `m` before the designated process or after the designated process has loaded the file contents. If there is a more elegant way, I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to use named interprocess mutexex. See e.g. the example(s) in Boris Schälings "Boost" Book, which is freely available, also online: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-synchronization

If your segment creation is already suitably synchronized, you can use "unnamed" interprocess mutices inside your shared segment, which is usually more efficient and avoids polluting system namespaces with extraneous synchronization primitives.

Comment: That book reference looks great and thank you for taking time to reply. That said, how would using just a mutex alone work in this situation? I thought about this and suppose I use a mutex that must be locked when `process(1)` goes to load the file contents and must also be locked when any other process goes to read the shared memory data, how can I be sure that `process(1)` will lock the mutex first so the data is setup for other processes? Seems that this cannot work on its own.

Comment: I think I might have found a way to solve my problem by adding in a condition variable and a boolean variable in the shared memory segment, but I am still curious to hear your response to my above concerns in case there's a better way.

Comment: Are you saying I didn't answer the question? In that case, perhaps you can clarify what part you're missing.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough in my original post, see my edit to the question and see if that helps you see what my dilemma is (and if I am overthinking it).